# Mongo auditable ZonedDateTime fields don't work in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In a Spring Boot project, I use annotations like @CreatedDate to save information about dates when the corresponding documents are created / updated. ZonedDateTime is used throughout the project, so the annotated fields are ZonedDateTime, too. To enable conversion between the Mongo's date format and ZonedDateTime, custom converters are used.

Now, when using Spring Boot 1.5.x, the custom converters work perfectly for the auditable fields. In Spring Boot 2.0.x, the custom converters work for all fields, but not for the auditable ones. Thus, if I remove @EnableMongoAuditing, everything works fine (all ZonedDateTime fields throughout the project are persisted to and read from Mongo correctly), but the created / updated date fields are empty. If I enable mongo auditing, I get the following exception when trying to save a document:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date type for member <MEMBER NAME>!
Supported types are [org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]
```

My Mongo config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter());
        converters.add(new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

This is how the corresponding fields look like:

```
abstract class BaseModel {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime created;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime updated;
}
```

Is there a way to make the converters work for mongo auditable fields, other than downgrading to Spring Boot 1.5.x?

Comment: FYI, I changed the type to java.util.Date and use custom accessors, but this doesn't look elegant, and I feel that I'm missing something obvious here. It used to work, there must be a reason why it doesn't now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### **TL;DR:**

Besides register a `MongoCustomConversions` bean. Create a bean of `DateTimeProvider`, and register it into your `@EnableXXXAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")`

```java
public class CustomDateTimeProvider implements DateTimeProvider {

    @Override
    public Optional<TemporalAccessor> getNow() {
        return Optional.of(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider") // beanName
public class MongoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter());
        converters.add(new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    // The DateTimeProvider bean with beanName="dateTimeProvider" is registered here
    @Bean
    public DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider() {
        return new CustomDateTimeProvider();
    }
}
```

---

##### **FYI**:

When you use `@EnableXXXAuditing`, Spring will register a [AuditHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditingHandler.html) that is responsible for adding auditing data to your model. It has 2 main components: [DateTimeProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/auditing/DateTimeProvider.html) and [AuditorAware<?>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AuditorAware.html). You could register these 2 components in `AuditHandler` by declaring them in `@EnableXXXAuditing`. For example:

```java
@EnableXXXAuditing(
    auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware", // beanName
    dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider" // beanName
)
```

- **DateTimeProvider** in short, is responsible for `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate`
- **AuditorAware** in short, is responsible for `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy`

The default implementation of `DateTimeProvider` is **CurrentDateTimeProvider** that returns a instance of `LocalDateTime`. That's why you got the error with your `ZonedDateTime` CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate.